# php bug? reading mime enc on a 1 byte file?

Tags: php, mime

So I was encountering a smaller problem in my PHP code, which I suspect it being a PHP bug? if not, then what am i doing wrong.

(the part of the code that caused the error, NOT all of my code)

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_ENCODING);
$mime_enc = finfo_file($finfo, $root.$file); // <-- this is the error line
```

This specific code ONLY caused an error when reading a 1 byte file (a file with 1 character in it) it did NOT throw errors when checking mime of a 0 byte or 2+ byte file

> ( ! ) Warning: finfo_file(): Failed identify data 0:(null)

using:
Wampserver 2.5 (32 bit)
windows 7

Comment: I tried in on PHP 5.6.10 (Wampserver 2.5 seems to have 5.5.12) on Fedora 22, and it works fine.

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64684